# ThreeJS - 2D pixels to 3D coordinates conversion

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am trying to render a `cube` created in ThreeJS onto a HTML `canvas` at a particular position.

I have the position in pixels. Like (100,200).
I cannot figure out how to convert these pixels to ThreeJS coordinates.

```
// My canvas is 640 X 480
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;

// Create and cube to scene
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var materials = createMaterials();
this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
this.cube.doubleSided = true;
this.scene.add(this.cube);

// Create and add camera
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 5000);
this.camera.position.z = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
this.scene.add(this.camera);
```

I noticed that (0,0) in ThreeJS is actually in the center of the screen.

How do I convert any 2D coordinates from my canvas to 3D coordinates that work with ThreeJS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to snip a specific area of the three.js canvas, and move its image data over to another canvas? I'm not sure how mapping 2D to 3D is going to help with that. Could you just use `canvas.toDataURL`, load the result into an `Image`, and then use `canvas.putImage`?

Comment: No, I just want to position the center of the cube at the desired coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Just an option of how you can do it, using `THREE.Raycaster()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(box);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var dist = box.position.clone().sub(camera.position).length();

  raycaster.ray.at(dist, box.position);

}


renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you can do something similar, using a raycaster and `THREE.Plane()`, finding the intersection point of raycaster's ray with the plane.

Comment: The cube also changes perspective when removed from the center. Anyway to keep it in its initial state but only change its position and not skew it?

Comment: @dydx There always will be distortion, when you use PerspectiveCamera.

Answer (score 0):

First of all three js scene renders a 3Diamensonal which means to set position of your object should have all 3D co-ordinates ie.(X,Y,Z) in your
scene if you want to change the position of your object use
`Object.position.set( x , y , z );`
In which z position is used to put the objects position near far from camera [image][image]
Good luck
Put the z value 0 so you can put your object at the required co-ordinates (x,y,0)