# ThreeJS world unit to pixel conversion

Tags: three.js, pixel, viewport

Is there a way compute the ratio between world unit and pixels in ThreeJS ? I need to determine how many units apart my objects need to be in order to be rendered 1 pixel apart on the screen.

The camera is looking at the (x,y) plane from a (0, 0, 10) coordinate, and objects are drawn in 2D on the (x,y) plane at z=0.

```
<Canvas gl={{ alpha: true, antialias: true }} camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10] }}>
```

I cannot seem to figure out what the maths are or if there is any function that does it already...
I'm thinking I might have to compare the size of the canvas in pixels and world units, but I dont know how to get that either. There's also [this raycasting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381278/threejs-2d-pixels-to-3d-coordinates-conversion), but surely there has to be a way to just compute it, no ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a pretty complex issue due to perspective. Things that are closer to the camera appear larger than far away ones, which means that a world unit will have different pixel magnitudes based on depth. Their position within the camera frustum, and resizing the window will also affect this ratio.

Comment: @Marquizzo is that so regardless of the type of camera used ?

Comment: I guess an Orthographic camera would get rid of the perspective distortions.